# How to share audio on Telegram

Tags: android, audio, share, telegram

I want to make a button to share an audio file on Telegram.
I have problems only with Telegram (sharing on whatsapp works fine).

My audio file is in raw folder, and i tried with .mp3, .wav and .m4a extensions, but if i try to share audio on telegram i get the toast "Unsupported attachment".

That's my share method:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/m4a");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + ctx.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.my_audio));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share on:"));
```

Answer (score 6):

use "Uri.fromFile", this worked for me.

```
                File file = new File(filePath);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("audio/*");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,
                        "به اشتراک گذاشتن فایل"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Android apps will not handle the ill-used `android.resource://` scheme. If you want better compatibility, write the audio to a file and share that, or use a `ContentProvider` (e.g., [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider)) to serve it via a `content://` scheme.

Comment: How can i use ContentProvider?

Comment: @genialFactory: You would have to write one that would pipe the resource content back from `openFile()` or possibly `openAssetFile()`. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/GrantUriPermissions) shows the basic concept, though it uses a file in `assets/` rather than a raw resource.